# Django Rest Framework: get multiple source fields from reverse relation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=250)
    content = models.TextField('Content')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    b = models.ForeignKey('bs.B', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='b', related_name='as')

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField('Description')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to serialize my `B` model and include multiple fields in it, but not all of them. Creating serializer like this:

```
class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a_items = ASerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='as')

    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = '__all__'
```

gives me `B` objects with `a_items` field, containing all of `A` fields, but I would like to get only `name` and `content`. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782993/django-rest-framework-multi-source-field) question and the answer, but unfortunately, since DRF 3.0, it no longer supports `field_to_native()` method. I would be grateful for any kind of hints where to start with this, since even trying to add `source='as.name'` doesn't seem to work and related objects just disappear. I tried with some random string following `as.` and it still does not fail, even though I would expect that.

Comment: Why dont you change your `ASerializer()` to only display the  `name` and `content` fields?

Comment: I do not want to change it, because I need to get whole `A` object in other place, but here I only need specific fields.

Comment: Create two serializers: one that returns everything, and one that returns `name` and `content`. Use the latter here and the former wherever is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I would say it's super-hacky and I hope there's better way to do this, but I managed to bend `to_representation()` to show what I need:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super(BSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    data['a_items'] =self._get_foreign_key_values(data)
    return data

def _get_foreign_key_values(self, data):
    return [dict(name=value['name'], content=value['content']) for value in data]
```